# Agregar Etiqueta UWP debería crearse

Tags: discusión, característica-nueva, etiquetas

Las Aplicaciones Universales de Windows10 ya son una realidad, se etiquetan con UWP (Universal Windows Plataform) me gustaría que se agregará esa etiqueta y no ser si tambien w10 (desktop), w10m (mobile), dependiendo del target, ya que puede ser de ámbito universal pero especificamente en solo una plataforma.

Más información de las UWP:
[Guía de aplicaciones de Plataforma universal de Windows (UWP)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/windows/apps/dn894631.aspx)

Comment: ya fue creada por @CarlosMuñoz en el edit de tu pregunta! abrazo.

Answer (score 1):

Puedes seguir la sugerencia de esta respuesta: [La etiqueta express o expressjs no se ha creado](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/340/la-etiqueta-express-o-expressjs-no-se-ha-creado)

Aquí te dejo el screenshot:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]