# La etiqueta express o expressjs no se ha creado

Tags: discusión, característica-nueva, etiquetas

[Express.js](http://expressjs.com/) es un framework para crear aplicaciones en [Node.js](https://nodejs.org/en/). Es uno de los más populares de esa plataforma y es la base de muchos otros frameworks que ofrecen un mayor nivel de abstracción. en el momento de escribir este post cuenta con [19621](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/express) preguntas en stackoverflow en inglés.

Actualmente esta etiqueta no existe, ¿Podría alguien crearla?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Cualquier usuario con un mínimo de 300 de reputación puede agregar una nueva etiqueta como lo indica [Privilegios > Crear Etiquetas](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/create-tags).

Simplemente publica una pregunta utilizando la etiqueta que sea apropiada, no es necesario hacer una solicitud en meta, ocurrirá de manera automática.

Comment: También es posible crear la etiqueta por usuarios con privilegios de edición al editar una pregunta y agregar la nueva etiqueta.